# Getting 403() error while using google Youtube API

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am gating this Error when i use Youtube API

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=************"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions."
 }
}
```

and 403() error it's showing in console

Comment: add your code.what you are trying to do

Comment: I am trying to fetch videos from the youtube channel using YCP jquery plugin  $(".videos").ycp({
        apikey : '******************************************',
        autoplay : true,
        related : false
      });